# Dirac equation in higher dimensional spacetimes

Tags: black-holes, dirac-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I would like to understand the Dirac equation in higher dimensional curved spacetimes. I have seen there are some crucial points like the spin connection and the introduction of the Newman-Penrose formalism in order to decouple the differential equations and the fields. Does anybody know a detailed and clear reference to study with? If there are available references related with the scattering off the fermionic fields around black holes I will appreciate it.

Comment: You are looking for references where the higher dimensional version of Dirac and other wave equations are discussed?

Comment: Yes. I'm also interested in a derivation of the Newman-Penrose formalism for higher dimensions

Comment: I don't know about N-P formalism. But for higher dimensional wave equation, you may consult with: "Wave Equations in Higher Dimensions" by Shi-Hai Dong, published by: Springer Verleg.

Comment: I think QFT in curved space has spin fields in a general relativity background. Don't know if they cover the NP formalism

Comment: Probably not clear. QFT in Curved Space is a book. Can Google it